# In case of web applications, why java is also called platform independent?

Tags: java, web, cross-platform

In case of desktop applications, it is clear that Java is a platform independent, because you do not need to compile the java desktop application on each OS to run appropriately.. it is enough to have a JVM installed on the targeted OS, to run the application.

But I can not see that concept clearly in case of web applications, because if you want to run a web that developed in Java programming language, you need a JDK installed in the server and an apache (especially Tomcat) web server, and once the web is created, it will stay on the server and it will be requested with a client web browser. This is the opposite of the previous case (desktop applications), in which each client must obtain a .jar file to run the java application (independently of his OS).

So where is the irony? 
And how can we benefit from the platform-independent issue in that case?

Comment: The word you are looking for is “software stack”.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Java is platform independent

That means that Java can *run* on any platform with a JRE installed, without having to recompile the code.

For desktop applications, that means the *desktop computer* can be Windows, Linux, macOS, etc.

For web applications<sup>1</sup>, that means the *server machine* can be Windows, Linux, macOS, etc.

It is exactly the same thing. No irony.

<sup>*1) Note that web applications don't necessarily require any "Apache web server". You can write Java web applications that are their own web server software. All that is needed is the JRE.*</sup>

Comment: In fact, _most_ Java Web applications these days use Java Web servers, and new ones almost always include their own Web server as part of the launcher jar.

Comment: @Andreas
Yes, it was right what you said, but the idea is - in case of web applications -, if you have a dependent platform like c++, you will compile it for one time, and put it on the server, and then you will let it work. And no need to recompile it on every user pc because he will request the app by the web browser. That why I can not see a benefit from using a platform-independent app in this case. What actually is the benefit from using a platform-independent app in this case?

Comment: @user9152856 1) If you're selling a webapp, you don't know what kind of server your customer will be running. 2) If your IT department decides to change servers, e.g. from Windows to Linux, or 32-bit to 64-bit, or ARM to X86, etc. 3) Allows testing the *exact same* version of your webapp on your desktop as will be running on the server. --- But why does it matter that the fact that Java is platform independent isn't as big of a deal for web apps as it is for desktop apps? It is just one of the many features you consider when choosing a language.

Comment: Yes, these 3 options are what I intended to hear. Great!